# Prevent Android Studio from adding jcenter to build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jcenter

I'm using Android Studio 4.2.1 and see warnings about jcenter being deprecated.
When I create an empty activity, it includes

`jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon`

in the build.gradle script.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: There are questions here about changing the default templates, or adding your own, but the answers all seem to be for versions <= 4.1 and don't seem to apply to the newer version.